# Write a program using a loop that outputs the following program

Tags: c, printf, output

So i have written a program that converts degrees to radians and then prints the result as the output.

```
 CODE (website not phone friendly)
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define PI 3.141593
 int main (){
     int degrees =10;
     double radians;
     printf("Degrees to Radians \n");

     while( degrees <= 360){
         radians = degrees*PI/180;
         printf("%6i %9.6f \n", degrees, radians);
        degrees +=10;
     }
 }
 END CODE
```

So I would like to be able to make this program the actual output that my program creates. I had someone suggest to me fprintf but they did not elaborate. Im new to c programming, can anyone explain how I could use fprintf ( broad idea maybe?). I understand that fprint is another way to print output but thats about it.

Comment: Print to `stdout`? `fprintf()` maybe a overkill for that.

Comment: Do you know how to use escape sequences? Inside a string literal (`"this is a string literal"`), `\n` represents a newline, `\"` represents a double quote, and ``\\`` represents a backslash. Making use of those representations will let you represent your code as a string literal, which you can then print like anything else (using `puts` or `printf` or…).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `fprintf` in your code

```
int main() {
    FILE * fp;
     int degrees =10;
     double radians;
     printf("Degrees to Radians \n");
    fp = fopen("radians.txt","w+");
     while( degrees <= 360){
         radians = degrees*PI/180;
         printf("%6i %9.6f \n", degrees, radians);
         fprintf(fp, "%6i\t%9.6f \n", degrees, radians);
        degrees +=10;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

here i added `\t` inside fprintf to get a tab space. And `"w+"` in fopen will create new file with the given name, So all your out put will be saved in a file.

Comment: I tried this but what I actually would like to do is to make the program the output. So that when I run the program the actual output is the program above not the degrees to radian conversion.